How do I automatically add a new line at the end of a file so GitHub doesn't complain?
GitHub complains if a file does not end with a blank line:

Is there a way to automatically add one so I don't have to do remember to do it for every file?

Popular IDEs can do this automatically:
VS Code
File (Code if using a Mac) → Preferences → Settings → Files: Insert Final Newline

IntelliJ IDEA
Settings → Editor → General → Ensure line feed at file end on save

